# Angular UI-Router wih empty ui-sref and load once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this sidebar.html:

```
<ul id="menu-sidebar">
    <li class="has_sub" ng-repeat="menu in menus | filter: filterTier | filter: filterRole">
        <a ng-if="menu.url != '#'" ui-sref="{{ menu.url }}" class="waves-effect" ui-sref-active="active subdrop">
            <i class="fa fa-{{ menu.icon }}"></i> <span> {{ menu.name }}</span>
        </a>
        <a ng-if="menu.url == '#'"  class="waves-effect" ui-sref-active="active subdrop" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-{{ menu.icon }}"></i> <span> {{ menu.name }}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-if="menu.sub_menus.length > 0">
            <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.sub_menus">
                <a ui-sref="{{ submenu.url }}" ui-sref-active="active">{{ submenu.name }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And my appController.js:

```
$scope.menus = [{name: 'Customers', url: 'customers', icon: 'users', tier: 1, role: 1},
    {name: 'Settings', url: '#', icon: 'gear', tier: 1, role: 1,
        sub_menus: [{name: 'Admin', url: 'settings.admin'}, {name: 'Outlet', url: 'settings.outlet'} ]
    }];
```

Those code above will produce sidebar menu.

Yes above code is worked perfectly.

I've got 2 questions:

1. As above I need to repeat my `<a>` tag and hide it manually if it '#' because it always return me an error if I put `#` or blank inside `ui-sref = {{menu.url}}`
2. How can I create my sidemenu only once?. Right now my controller will load the `$scope.menus` every time the page is loaded (I define it as appController and put it on my body tag so it always return me those menu).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As a tag and ui-router are used for going to a link so of course they will give you error if you don't give address to them.
2. Try this :


   `$( document ).ready(function() {
              //your code
         })/`

Comment: Hi!. i need ask why `$ionic`? Thanks.

Comment: aren't you using ionic ? if no then go for $(document) fun.

Comment: hi, i'm using angular no ionic. will `$(document).ready`  same as `$(viewContentLoaded)`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake and yes it is. It simple jquery and the code written in it will be loaded once.

Comment: so how about my first question? . is there  any shorten solution?

Comment: @SSuhat, I don't understand why you are using both of them together as they do the same piece of work. if you replace the <a> with any other tag may be a <div> even then you will get routed to your state inside ui-sref

Comment: actually some of my menu has sub menu. That's why some of the menu need '#' url. but its okay. Will stick with my solution